# Primary Key in Synapse Serverless SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, data-lakehouse

How can I create a primary key to an Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Database table?

I tried this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [silver].[table]
(
     [MATNR] char(100) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = 'file/tables/bronze_MARA',
    DATA_SOURCE = dsrc,
    FILE_FORMAT = formatparquet
)
ALTER TABLE [silver].[table] ADD PRIMARY KEY (MATNR);
```

But Synapse serverless does not allow NOT NULL

Also tried this in create table part:

```
[MATNR] char(100) primary key NONCLUSTERED NOT ENFORCED
```

returns:
'NOT ENFORCED' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

and if all columns must be nullable, I cant add any kind of key?

Is it possible at all to add a key on serverless synapse table?

This doesnt work for me, its referring to a dedicated pool:
[NOT NULL is not allowed for external table columns in Azure Synapase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71933733/not-null-is-not-allowed-for-external-table-columns-in-azure-synapase)

As I use serverless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. It's important to recognize that "[Serverless SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview)" is not SQL Server, meaning these aren't actual database objects, and these aren't really Tables. It's akin to Polybase, an abstraction of a schema overlaid on top of text files at runtime. As a result, while the query syntax is SQL, SQL concepts like Indexes and Keys (and many others) are not supported. This is why storage partitioning and well-defined schemas are very important to enhance performance.